# Find shorterst path length in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

How can I find the shortest path **length** in OrientDB?
There are a lot of examples how to find the shortest path, but there must be a way to get only the length of this path?

So instead of a list of vertices [like with this query](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/gettingstarted/demodb/queries/DemoDB-Queries-Shortest-Paths.html)

```
SELECT expand(path) FROM (

  SELECT shortestPath($from, $to) AS path 

  LET 

    $from = (SELECT FROM Profiles WHERE Name='Santo' and Surname='OrientDB'), 

    $to = (SELECT FROM Countries WHERE Name='United States') 

  UNWIND path

)
```

I would just like a single number as result.

I am using Java to query the DB, so a Java API function is also OK.

Comment: Can't you get the length of the list? Unless there is weight associated with the edges, the length will be n - 1. a->b->c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(path.size()) FROM (

  SELECT shortestPath($from, $to) AS path 

  LET 

    $from = (SELECT FROM Profiles WHERE Name='Santo' and Surname='OrientDB'), 

    $to = (SELECT FROM Countries WHERE Name='United States') 

  UNWIND path

)
```

Hope it helps.

Regards